# Admin Panel not displaying correctly under SSL

Tags: admin-login

Running 1.7.0.2 and we just switched the Secure Admin flag to "yes."  However, when we navigate to admin using https:// text displays but no pictures/formatting/etc...

The error console shows multiple errors like this when trying to load CSS/JS files:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.com/admin/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://website.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

"Use Secure URLs in Frontend" and "Use Secure URLs in Admin" drop down boxes are both set to 'Yes.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to the certificate being used over a different URL from the actual site.  Once we updated to the actual cert and matching URL everything cleared up.